# Query not giving the expected results in PHP

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to retrieve values from 2 tables in the database.
The PHP looks like this:

```
$conn = Db::getInstance();
$getPosts = $conn->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT board.boardID, 
board.userID, board.postID, items.Url, items.Image
FROM board
JOIN items on postID = items.id
WHERE board.userID = 92, board.boardID = 1");
$getPosts->execute();
$p = $getPosts->fetch();

var_dump($p);
```

I was expecting an array with all the values in it but instead, $p gives me a bool(false). I'd like to echo $p['Url'] in an image tag.
What am I doing wrong?
Much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace the comma in the WHERE clause with an AND.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Max

Answer (score 1):

When You have error in your SQL query syntax, it returns boolean "false" that's where you are having problem

Comment: Thank you @Alien Whale, I did not know that